# AxaptaContainerWrapper Class .net AX 2009

Tags: c#, .net, axapta

I would like to use `AxaptaContainerWrapper` object in .net c#. I don't understand documentation on MSDN web site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc519742%28v=ax.50%29.aspx).

AxaptaContainerWrapper axCon;

```
string ret2 = "axCon";

axCon.Insert(1, ret2);
```

In VS 2008 I get error Use of unassigned local variable `axCon`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use axaptaWrapper.CreateAxaptaObject() method: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc599500.aspx)

```
AxaptaWrapper aw= SessionManager.GetSession();
AxaptaObjectWrapper aow= ax.CreateAxaptaObject("??");
```

Comment: I tried it I got Error 4 The type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Reports.AxaptaWrapper' has no constructors

Comment: Constructor is not public. Do you have acces to `AxaptaWrapper` class instance? If yes, you could use `axaptaWrapper.CreateAxaptaObject()` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc599500.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code below and I haven't any errors. I have to make all report to test it

```
     AxaptaWrapper ax = SessionManager.GetSession();
    AxaptaObjectWrapper axClass;

    AxaptaContainerWrapper axCon = ax.CreateAxaptaContainer();
```